# EF - Difference between calling a view using SqlQuery and directly calling a SQL Query using SqlQuery method

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to call a view from EF using `SqlQuery` method which connects to an Oracle database, and I see a performance issue: for just 10 k to 30 k (at least takes 15 secs to bind it to view which has around 10 columns).

I just want to know if I can use query directly in `SqlQuery` method not the view instead and needs to know if there would be any improvement in performance.

Any suggestions please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't **call a view** - you **select from it** - a view is not something you can **call** (or execute - like a stored procedure) - it's like a table from which you can select rows

Comment: @marc_s - Thats what I am trying to do here. I am trying to select using SqlQuery from a view which is what my problem is

Comment: Why don't you just include the view into your EF data model?? Why revert back to "raw" SQL if you're using EF in the first place ??

Comment: Hey Marc, I am facing some issues in pulling the view into EF data model as it is Oracle and I need to have right set of Oracle tools installed in my machine. I need to go through many approvals in order to get those as there are a few restrictions to get tools and extension. So I tried this and facing some issues. It's just a trail and error I am doing here.

Comment: Sorry, I am not using Oracle, and I don't know much about Oracle, so I really cannot help you here.....